# converter inteiro para decimal em jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso converter por exemplo o valor **"025"** 
para **"0.25"** ou **"005"** para **"0.05"**:

Estou tentando faze assim:

```
var valor1 = $("#ValorDesconto").val().replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');
parseFloat(valor1).toFixed(2)
```

Como faço ? do jeito que fiz acima é sempre acrescentado dois zeros a direita:
exemplo:
de **"025"** para **"25.00"** ou **"005"** para **"5.00"**.

Aqui está o código completo:

```
var valor1 = $("#ValorUnitario").val().replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');
var valor2 = $("#ValorDesconto").val().replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');

                    var _produto = {
                        "PaoID": $("#SelPao").val(),
                        "FermentacaoID": $("#SelFermentacao").val(),
                        "Observacao": $("#Observacao").val(),
                        "Status": true,
                        "ValorUnitario": Number(valor1).toFixed(2),
                        "ValorDesconto": Number(valor2).toFixed(2)
                    };
                    console.log(_produto);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Administrativo/Produto/SalvarJSON",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
                        processData: false,
                        data: JSON.stringify(_produto),
                        beforeSend: function () {
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                        },
                        success: function (data) {

                            if (data.ok == true) {
                                window.location.href = "/Administrativo/Produto/Index";
                            } else {
                                $("#advertenciaModal .modal-body").html("<div>" + data.msg + "</div>");
                                $("#advertenciaModal").modal();
                            };

                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            window.location.href = "/Administrativo/Produto/Index";
                        }
                    });
```

Usei `Number(valor1).toFixed(2)` como sugestão do Otto mas sem efeito

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) do Javascript para formatar

```js
var valor = "025";
var len = valor.length;
var valorFormatado = valor.substring(0, len - 2) + "." + valor.substring(len - 2);
console.log(valor);
console.log(valorFormatado);
```

Explicando:

- `valor.substring(0, len - 2)`: obtém uma string a partir do índice `0` até dois antes do último.
- `+ "." +`: concatena um ponto entre as duas strings.
- `valor.substring(len - 2)`: obtém os dois últimos dígitos.
- `valorFormatado`: terá a string com um ponto antes dos dois últimos dígitos.

Na sequência, você pode converter para float/decimal usando `parseFloat(valorFormatado)`

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Você poderia fazer desta maneira

```
Number(1).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: editei a pergunta com a sugestão e não funcionou.

Comment: @AdrianoSUV engraçado que no print aparece certo, o erro é de uma imagem que esta faltando.

Comment: Olá @Otto do jeito que você postou não dá erro, o problema é que não converte do jeito que to querendo se você observar no print temos por exemplo ValorDesconto = "25,00" eu implementei a funçao Number e digitei no input "0,25" e converteu para "25,00".

Answer (score 2):

Se neste valor os dois últimos números são sempre as casas decimais então o mais simples seria dividir por 100

```
var _produto = {
    "PaoID": $("#SelPao").val(),
    "FermentacaoID": $("#SelFermentacao").val(),
    "Observacao": $("#Observacao").val(),
    "Status": true,
    "ValorUnitario": parseInt(valor1) / 100,
    "ValorDesconto": parseInt(valor2) / 100
};
```

Desta forma o valor está ficando como número mesmo no objeto, o que geralmente é o ideal, mas dependendo da sua necessidade pode ser que tenha que converter para string também

Comment: Dividir por 100 fica bem mais simples, nem tinha pensado nisso. +1

Comment: Boa!, realmente vou testar também.